# Will Magento 2.4.2-p1 run with PHP 8.1?

Tags: php

I have an 'older' site running **Magento 2.4.2-p1** on the same server as my new site I'm working on which is running Magento 2.4.5-p1.

I have previously reached out to our hosting asking about PHP version and this is what they said **in regards to our Magento 2.4.5-p1**:

*Be aware that the Global PHP on your server is 7.3. However, your website is using PHP 8.1.* (we have a MultiPHP Manager in our WHM where you can select different PHP versions for different accounts).

They said they can change global to PHP 8.1 but to **check whether that will run on our other account/website which is Magento 2.4.2-p1? Will switching Magento 2.4.2-p1 to PHP 8.1 work without problems?**

Answer (score 1):

No, according to magento 2's devdocs magento 2.4.2 7.4 php version is required.

for reference : [System requirements for magento 2](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/system-requirements.html)

however you can try alternatives to run magento 2 different versions by modifying htaccess files (try both htaccess file root or pub).

you may use this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

   AddHandler application/x-httpd-php71 .php
   RewriteEngine On

   ....

</IfModule>
```

or try this reference link: [how to use multi php versions using htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561203/how-to-change-php-version-in-htaccess-in-server)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I looked at the link you provided and I can see it shows 7.4. The interesting bit is, I switched the PHP version via the MultiPHP Manager in our WHM to 8.1 for my Magento 2.4.2-p1 site and it appears to be running fine so far. I may ask hosting if we switch the 'global php' to 8.1 and things go wrong, if they be able to put it back to 7.4.